# Looking for OPC DA client library

Tags: c#, .net, opc

I'm looking for freeware library to connect to OPC DA 2.x server. So far, everything I found has commercial licensing, which is not an option for this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the: OPC Foundation .NET API.

I believe it is freely available. (Not the source)

Alternatively, see http://www.opcconnect.com/ for a good summary

Comment: Good site, lots of stuff I'll have to check. I'm sure I'll found something there.

Comment: I've been using the OPC Foundation .NET API for 4 years.  

It is works well and is not hard to use.

Comment: Also, you want to consider OpenOPC at http://openopc.sourceforge.net/api.html.  I've used it for as part of a testing system.  It's easy, free, python based, and includes a good command line utility for ad-hoc browse/read/write opc function.

Comment: This is not freeware anymore.  It requires a membership.

Answer (score 0):

It is Java, but the OpenSCADA - Utgard Project might just be what you need.

If you need any help, just drop a line to Juergen DOT Rose AT inavare DOT net

http://www.openscada.org/